# How to Run my Asp.net Core application on Apache server on Windows?

Tags: apache, iis, asp.net-core

Asp.net core is open source and run on any os like Linux, Windows and Mac.
my question is. is it possible to run asp.net core application run on apache server publish on not on IIS server on Windows operating system.
thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no official Apache package for windows. Microsoft has no interest in developing such thing nor does apache developers have such interest. There are 3rd party packages like xampp but you will probably get stuck on that to. It is better to use ubuntu and apache to host asp.net core..

Answer (score 10):

There is no Apache mod to run ASP.NET Core application, however you can setup Apache or Nginx to be a reverse proxy for ASP.NET Core application running on Kestrel web server. This is actually what Microsoft recommends to do in production environment primarily for security reasons. For more details take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy). To see how exactly configure Apache reverse proxy take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy).